# What happens when we delete resolv.conf file from a Linux server?

Tags: deleted-files, resolv.conf

I have deleted the `resolv.conf` file from a Linux server and now I am not able to login to that server. What is the logic behind this and how can this be resolved?

Comment: How are you trying to log into it? SSH? VNC?

Comment: don't post same question on multiple SE sites, http://serverfault.com/questions/797594/what-happen-when-we-delete-resolv-conf-file-from-a-linux-server

Answer (score 4):

The `resolv.conf` file contains configuration of name servers and domains required to resolve names of other servers to their network addresses.

Per `man resolv.conf`:

> If this file does not exist, only the name server on the local  machine will be queried; the domain name is determined from the hostname and the domain search path is constructed from the domain name.

Removing the file should have no influence on the login:

- to a system console
- through SSH connection (with no login restrictions)

It will have an influence on the login:

- through SSH connection (with [host login restrictions](https://support.ssh.com/manuals/server-admin/44/Restricting_User_Logins.html)).
- with Kerberos / Active Directory authentication
- other custom authorization module depending on DNS

> how can this be resolved?

You should login to the server console and check if the file needs to be recreated.

---

Side note: if you were using DHCP, the file might be automatically recreated on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the file `/etc/resolv.conf` tells the system how to resolve network domain names.  Presumably you cannot connect because the server can no longer figure out what host you're coming from (probably to check security rules).

Without a `/etc/resolv.conf` file, you probably won't be able to do much over the network.  You'll probably need to go to the console to fix this.

In summary, `resolv.conf` is a critical configuration file for the system.  Without it the system will not function fully.

Answer (score 0):

`man resolv.conf` says:

> The  resolver  is  a  set of routines in the
>   C library that provide access to the Internet Domain Name System
>   (DNS).  The resolver configuration file contains information that is
>   read by the resolver
>          routines the first time they are invoked by a process.  The file is designed to be human readable and contains a list of keywords
>   with values that provide various types of resolver information.   The
>          configuration file is considered a trusted source of DNS information (e.g., DNSSEC AD-bit information will be returned
>   unmodified from this source).
>
> If this file does not exist, only the name server on the local machine will be queried; the domain name is determined from the
>   hostname and the domain search path is constructed from the domain
>   name.

If you do not have this file or deleted then (at least for Ubuntu), you can recreate the file by executing command:

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp # ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
SHW@SHW:/tmp # resolvconf -u
```